# Implementation of a dropdown list in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to implement a dropdown list in HTML/CSS and more specifically in React. I've found a tutorial here showing something that could interest me : [Link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BXRyzg)

The only problem is that when I include this code and modify it a little in my React project nothing appends... It seems to be a problem of bootstrap but I can't identify it. 
Here is what happens : 
[image]

Here is my code :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./VerticalDots.css";


export default class VerticalDots extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <img src={require("../imgs/3dots-vertical.png")} alt="NotFound"/>
        </button>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li>0123 4567 8912 3456</li>
          <li>0123 4567 8912 3456</li>
          <li>0123 4567 8912 3456</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

A little help would be much appreciated !

Comment: the `ul` should also have `aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton"` with the name `dropdownMenuButton` the same as the id of your button check it [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/dropdowns/#single-button)

Comment: Did you require bootstrap.js and bootstrap.css in your project? Do you see any error in the console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are not loading Bootstrap's assets. In the codepen you linked, you can see that, under "Settings > CSS" and "Settings > JavaScript", Bootstrap is required.

To load them, you must import them from your bundle, for instance if you use webpack, in `App.js`

```js
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js';
```

Another option is to use a CDN, like Codepen does, but you probably want the above for a production build.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by adding :

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js';
```

Comment: Rather than post how you solved it as _an "answer"_, you should **accept** Matthieu Libeer's answer.